# RTSP support library for Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gstreamer, rtsp, vlcj

I am new to this Javafx. I need to know rtsp supported library for Javafx I knew few of the media library GStreamer and VLCJ.  I don't know which will support this features in Javafx. I have read many portals which I cant get an answer. many of them posted you cant run RTSP in Javafx. please guide me which library is best for RTSP that will support for Javafx.

```
 File f = new File("Video.mp4");
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    /*I dont know where to add the playerComponent as we do in swing*/
    MediaPlayer mp=playerComponent.getMediaPlayer();       
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);        
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

This is the normal video player in Javafx.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer but I saw the question while I had the same question so check this site out I think it got all the things I have to say https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX/blob/master/README.md#frameworks